# Selenium for Application testing

Tags: selenium

Good Morning everyone!

We have a piece of software at my work which we are currently automating with a paid automation tool. However all of the components are web forms, even though this is an installed application and not run out of a browser in anyway.

Would it be possible, or more beneficial to use Selenium to automate this? or would Selenium not be able to handle this since it is technically not browser automation?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately selenium cannot be used for desktop application, you may have to use some different tool. I had gone through some tutorials of [JSoup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup)(a Java extension), but it will take efforts to use it.

Another method to test is by developing your own script in VBScript or JavaScript by using WScript.Shell object and then navigate through Sendkeys method, it does not take much efforts if you know how to use it.